# why DriverManager.getConnection does not use "acceptsURL" method from Driver.class

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm reading JDBC code. In DriverManager.getConnection, I find it works like this: it tries to connect every Driver it knows until it success.

Here is the code:

```
        for(DriverInfo aDriver : registeredDrivers) {
            // If the caller does not have permission to load the driver then
            // skip it.
            if(isDriverAllowed(aDriver.driver, callerCL)) {
                try {
                    println("    trying " + aDriver.driver.getClass().getName());
                    Connection con = aDriver.driver.connect(url, info);
                    if (con != null) {
                        // Success!
                        println("getConnection returning " + aDriver.driver.getClass().getName());
                        return (con);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    if (reason == null) {
                        reason = ex;
                    }
                }

            } else {
                println("    skipping: " + aDriver.getClass().getName());
            }

        }
```

But there is a method "acceptsURL" from interface Driver:

```
    boolean acceptsURL(String url) throws SQLException;
```

So my question is, why DriverManager does not call this method before it do the real connection to filter unrelated drivers?

Or with code, may be this is better?

```
        for(DriverInfo aDriver : registeredDrivers) {
            // If the caller does not have permission to load the driver then
            // skip it.
            if(isDriverAllowed(aDriver.driver, callerCL) && aDriver.driver.acceptsURL(url)) {
                try {
                    println("    trying " + aDriver.driver.getClass().getName());
                    Connection con = aDriver.driver.connect(url, info);
                    if (con != null) {
                        // Success!
                        println("getConnection returning " + aDriver.driver.getClass().getName());
                        return (con);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    if (reason == null) {
                        reason = ex;
                    }
                }

            } else {
                println("    skipping: " + aDriver.getClass().getName());
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DriverManager` reference implementation (OpenJDK) doesn't use `acceptsUrl`. That doesn't necessarily mean there are **no** `DriverManager` implementations using it. In fact, as far as I recall, earlier Sun Java implementations did call `acceptsURL`. The main reason it isn't called, is that the JDBC specification requires `DriverManager` to call `connect` on each registered driver anyway. See below.

Nothing in the specification or API documentation says that `DriverManager` must use `acceptsURL`. The [JDBC 4.3 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index3.html) on this only says (section 9.2 *The `Driver` interface*):

> The `DriverManager` class invokes `Driver` methods when it wishes to
>   interact with a registered driver. The `Driver` interface also
>   includes the method `acceptsURL`. The `DriverManager` **can** use this
>   method to determine which of its registered drivers it should use for
>   a given URL.

(emphasis mine)

Note the use of the word *can* instead of *must* or *will*.

The subsequent paragraph says:

> When the `DriverManager` is trying to establish a connection, it calls
>   that driver’s `connect` method and passes the driver the URL. If the
>   `Driver` implementation understands the URL, it will return a
>   `Connection` object or throw a `SQLException` if a connection cannot
>   be maded *[sic]* to the database. If the `Driver` implementation does
>   not understand the URL, it will return `null`.

In addition, section 9.4 *The `DriverManager` class* says:

> - `getConnection` — the method the JDBC client invokes to establish a connection. The invocation includes a JDBC URL, which the
>     `DriverManager` passes to **each driver in its list until it finds
>     one whose `Driver.connect` method recognizes the URL**. That driver returns a `Connection` object to the `DriverManager`, which in turn
>     passes it to the application.

(emphasis mine)

How I read this, calling `Driver.connect` on each driver is required anyway, so there is no point for the implementation to call `acceptsURL`.

Now, as to why the JDBC specification is written this way, I don't know, and I'm a member of the JSR-221 (JDBC 4) Expert Group myself. When I joined the Expert Group the implementation (and specification) was already this way, so I'm not aware of its history. However, I'm not sure you'll get a better answer here than above unsatisfactory answer (it is so because the specification says so).

However, if I had to guess, it is probably to do with the fact that for some drivers determining if they can accept an URL could be relatively complex or expensive. In that case it is better to just try and connect, because for a driver rejecting the URL the cost is (or should be) the same as just calling `acceptsURL`, while for a driver that will actually accept the URL, the cost would be hit twice if `DriverManager` would first call `acceptsURL` followed by a `connect`.

This doesn't mean that the `acceptsURL` method is entirely without value. Some applications (eg some query tools or reporting tools) use it to discover which driver(s) would handle a specific URL, so they can interrogate the `Driver` implementation(s) for their supported connection properties ([`Driver.getPropertyInfo​`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Driver.html#getPropertyInfo(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties))) so they can populate there connection wizard with the available properties. Other programs could use it to get information like its version ([`Driver.getMajorVersion`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Driver.html#getMajorVersion()), [`Driver.getMinorVersion`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Driver.html#getMinorVersion())), parent logger ([`Driver.getParentLogger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Driver.html#getParentLogger())) or JDBC compliancy ([`Driver.jdbcCompliant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Driver.html#jdbcCompliant())).